# Phantomjs script run even though local Highcharts exporting server turned off

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

Had installed both phantomjs and highcharts export server on my local machine. I'm running a script through phantomjs similar to https://joekuan.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/phantomjs-a-new-way-for-running-highcharts-on-the-server-side/

```
var svg = page.evaluate(function(opt) {

    Highcharts.setOptions ( {
      exporting: {
        url:'http://myserver:8080/export/'
      }
    } );

...

}, evalArg);

page.render(outputFilename); // save as png
phantom.exit();
```

It still able to save image even though myserver is down.

```
var chartOptions = {
   chart: {
       renderTo: 'container'
    },
    exporting: {
       url: 'http://myserver:8080/export/'
    },
    ...
};
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
```

Specifying the url under the chartOptions also doesn't help. It still able to save image even though myserver is down.

I even tried add it to

```
  return chart.getSVG({
      exporting: {
          url: 'http://myserver:8080/export/'
      }        
   });
```

but to no avail. 
Note: specifying the first option in jsp before the chart load works.
        Highcharts.setOptions ( {
          exporting: {
            url:'http://myserver:8080/export/'
          }
        } );

Anyone has any idea what's the correct way of passing my local export server url to Highcharts.

Thanks

Comment: Downloaded exporting.src.js and modified as follows:  getSVG: function (additionalOptions) {
        var chart = this,
            chartExportingOptions = chart.options.exporting,
            chartCopy,
            ...
            sourceHeight,
            exportUrl,
            ...;

Comment: ...
        sourceHeight = options.exporting.sourceHeight ||
            options.chart.height ||
            (/px$/.test(cssHeight) && parseInt(cssHeight, 10)) ||
            400;
        exportUrl = options.exporting.url || chartExportingOptions.url;

        // override some options
        extend(options.chart, {
            animation: false,
            ...
            height: sourceHeight,
            exporting: {
               url: exportUrl
            }
        });

Comment: Still not working. I don't see this in local exporting server if I ran the script through phantomjs. Feb 11, 2015 2:57:30 PM com.highcharts.export.interceptor.RequestInterceptor afterCompletion
INFO: Time=Wed Feb 11 14:57:30 SGT 2015 :: Time taken(ms) 943
 :: RequestMethod POST :: Status 200 :: Referer=http://myserver:8080/myApp/xxx.htm
Feb 11, 2015 2:57:30 PM com.highcharts.export.interceptor.RequestInterceptor afterCompletion
INFO: request count: 1, Error count: 0, Elapsed time (min): 13, Rate: 0

Comment: Even revert exporting.src.js and modified as follows: // Add the export related options
defaultOptions.exporting = {
    //enabled: true,
    //filename: 'chart',
    type: 'image/png',
    // url: 'http://export.highcharts.com/',
    url: 'http://myserver:8080/export/', it works even the local Highcharts exporting server is not started. Anyone know why? Thanks

Comment: I re-read the Export module @ http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview. At the bottom, there is a section "Saving images without using the export server. Some modern browsers also support saving content from HTML5 canvas directly. This can be used as a way of exporting charts without involving any server side conversion. Since Highcharts is drawn in SVG, we need a way to convert it to a HTML5 canvas. A library called canvg does a great job here ". Think because of this, export server is not called, so it doesn't matter what url you set. Am I correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, but above solution by Joe is to render charts on the server side. Meanwhile you are trying to replace Highcharts exporting server. I think you should install [this exporting server](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server). - which is not only phantomJS based. Highcharts are sending SVG data to the exporting server, while Joe's solution requires JSON options.

Comment: Hi Pawel, what I'm trying to do is to render charts on the server side as well as using the Highcharts exporting server on my local server. I had downloaded the codes from github, build the source and deploy the highcharts-export-web.war  to Tomcat. The rendering works fine, but I'm not sure where it sends the SVG data to. I want it to send to the local exporting server instead of Highcharts default one. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: http://myserver:8080/export/ is the url for Highcharts exporting server on my local server.

Comment: I just have tried to set any URL in the chart options: http://jsfiddle.net/b5y1ejfL/ - as you can see chart isn't exported, it's returning an error. The only thing comes to my mind is to update Highcharts library, maybe you are using version with some bug?

Comment: I'm using Highcharts JS v3.0.1, from Anna's post in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802528/how-to-save-an-image-of-the-chart-on-the-server-with-highcharts, she got the chart.getSvg() then do a post to the exporting server. Your reply "getSVG() creates copy of a chart from initial options and creates SVG" at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349258/highcharts-chart-getsvg-inconsistent-with-svg-on-the-page seem to suggest that when creating SVG no exporting server required. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are using outdated version of Highcharts, try to upgrade to 4.0.4. Anyway, it would be great to know what exactly you want to achieve.