# Can Highcharts be used to supply a PNG file to facebook via the meta og:image tag?

Tags: highcharts

I have the exporting feature set up and it works great for a user of the site, but I've no idea how I could make it work with the `<meta>` `og:image` tag?  Can someone point me in the right direction?  I've checked the documentation and couldn't find anything useful there, I sense maybe it's not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use similar structure inside `<head>` tags:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="your_page" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Some title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Some description" />
<meta property="og:image" content=".../chart.png" />
```

If you want image of a chart placed on a page to represent this page, you can export it and save it earlier and use it as a content for an `og:image` property. There are couple of pages worth seeing regarding this topic, like: http://ogp.me/,  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#testing. Also, here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ you can see how your markup appears to the Facebook Crawler.

Comment: the question is how do I automatically export the chart (which is dynamic and different all the time) to use as chart.png in your code

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. As I mentioned in my answer you can export image (for example on load event or on each chart update), save it somewhere on a server and then use it. The answer how to do it can be found for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802528/how-to-save-an-image-of-the-chart-on-the-server-with-highcharts.